# jquery serialize, get parameters and images

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, get

Ok, this one is weird, i have this code:

```
$('#nps').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var images = 'pic='+$('img[name="pic"]').attr('src');
    var inputs = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: "pages/"+page+".php?"+inputs+'&'+images+'&action='+param,
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        update(html);
    }).fail(function (){
        window.location = "/";
    });
});
```

What i'm trying to do is to pass to a php page some get parameters with the form inputs and the src of an image with the name pic.

The problam is that the pic param doesn't get passed all of the time, one time it is and the other it's not, randomally...

Comment: The problem is javascript doesn't do things randomly, you need to debug further to ensure that `$('img[name="pic"]')` always selects 1 image, and if it doesn't, figure out why and you'll have your answer.

Comment: i now use .first() and still no luck

Comment: `.first()` doesn't do any good if no images are selected though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly encoding your request parameters. Make sure you url encode them using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function:

```
$('#nps').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var images = encodeURIComponent($('img[name="pic"]').attr('src'));
    var inputs = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pages/' + page + '.php?pic=' + images + '&action=' + encodeURIComponent(param),
        type: 'POST',
        data: inputs,
        cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        update(html);
    }).fail(function (){
        window.location = "/";
    });
});
```

Now in your php script you will be able to use `$_GET['pic']` and `$_GET['action']` and then `$_POST['someFormElementName']` (for the form elements).

Comment: not related to question though might solve it, how can you use jquery to select all images with name artibute?

Comment: Like this: `$('img[name]')`. Oh and by the way I hope you are well aware that `name` is not a valid attribute for the `img` tag so it is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, but anyway you are looking for the [*`has attribute selector`*](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

Comment: any other ideas for an artibute, i was trying to make it like a form element :P

Comment: But an `img` tag is not a form element so what you are trying to do hardly makes sense.

Comment: thank you i solved it :) the problam wasn't even in this piece of code.. -_-